# python reading in from a text file fed via argument line

Tags: python

I enter this `python mapper1.py input.txt` in to the directory where the script is located. However, the console returns nothing just goes to the next line for more input after i press enter

```
import sys
import re    

def main(argv):
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
        contents = f.readline()
        line = contents
        # line = sys.stdin.readline()
        pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
        words = []

        while line:
            for word in pattern.findall(line):
                words.append(word.lower())
            line = sys.stdin.readline()

        words.sort()
        for w in words:
            print(w + "\t" + "1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv)
```

This is the error received after i exit

```
are     1
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "mapper1.py", line 24, in <module>
  main(sys.argv)
 File "mapper1.py", line 20, in main
  print(w + "\t" + "1")
 KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Formatting is still a bit off @xbonez ;)

Comment: @Goodies: I didn't want to fix the indentation of the definition of main since that might actually be the issue in his question :)

Comment: That indentation probably is the issue. After i fixed that I ran it and got 'no such file or directory error' when it tried to open the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while line:` loop never ends, because entering a "blank line" at the keyboard gives a carriage return character, which does count as **something**.

Comment: While this might be true, that would cause the script to hang up, not finish without doing anything.

Comment: He said _goes to the next line for more input after i press enter_, which seems consistent with an infinite loop.  He never said it finished.

Comment: mmk, I read that as the next bash prompt popping up, you know user@comp$

Comment: @JohnGordon what would be a suggested remedy for this? Could i say while line is not EMPTY? or ""

Comment: @JohnGordon Where exactly would i include the line, please clarify

Comment: Replace `line = sys.stdin.readline()` with `line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()`, inside the `while line:` loop.